# generate dynamic download link with deadline

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

i have some file on my server and want to download this file with one constraint by client.
clients should register until download file that is for past date(e.g more than 9 day).
for this reason, i decided that generate dynamic link to my files same as Rapidshare.com.
how do i this?

I am beginner!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a unique identifier (perhaps a GUID)
2. Associate this with a file name for download and an expiration date (in a DB, perhaps)
3. Create a page that takes the unique ID as a parameter
4. Have this page check the DB for the unique id and ensure it hasn't passed the expiration date
5. Send the file to the client, setting Content-Disposition header to attachment ([example](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=8))

Comment: with this way,can clients capture file path on server with explorer?
i don't want that clients knows file path!